# How to restrict access of a process to specific ports?

Tags: linux, port

How can I restrict access of a process to use only specific ports, or block it if it uses non-allowed ports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the process runs as a unique user id (i.e. the only processes running as that user are the ones you want to restrict), you could create iptables rules with "-m owner --uid-owner "

If you can't do that, apparmor (only really modern versions, although I'm not clear exactly what version started supporting it), or SELinux can do what you need.